# Adding a fade effect or preloading an li element for thumbnail slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a simple slider by reading and collecting information from tutorials.
It's here: http://codepen.io/thecuriousenggr/pen/KLbkj

But when I navigate left (or right), the element which disappears from the left and appears at right side is only displayed after the slide animation is over.

Is there any way to load it first (keeping it invisible) and then sliding it over so that it won't flash after the animation but will be present before the animation takes place.

Basically I'm looking for this -
1) I click right button
2) before the first li item goes to the left, it will be copied or duplicated to the extreme right hand side.
3) animation will take place.
4) the new duplicated one remains and old one gets removed.

That is my approach. But any other method will do as well. Help :)

Comment: I recently coded a gallery that does that.. it's not as simple as it seems :) basically to append the element to the opposite side and make it seem seamless and natural you need compensate the items width back into the position of the slider so you won't see a jump and begin the animation after you finished appending..

Comment: In your case there's even more work.. you have 4 slides and showing all 4.. usually to make this happened you would have at least one item over so it waits in position outside of view.. in your case you would need to clone the slide, because you want it to exit and enter from the other side at the same time.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code working none the less :)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AmIiz

what I changed is this:

```
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').outerWidth(true);
```

and these:

```
function moveLeft() {
      $('#slider ul').width(slideWidth*(slideCount+1))
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').clone().prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', - slideWidth).animate({'left': 0}, 333, function() {
             $('#slider ul').width(slideWidth*slideCount).css('left','');
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').remove();
              });

    };

    function moveRight() {
      $('#slider ul').width(slideWidth*(slideCount+1))
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').clone().appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').animate({'left': - slideWidth}, 333, function() {
              $('#slider ul').width(slideWidth*slideCount).css('left','');
      $('#slider ul li:first-child').remove();
              });
    };
```

let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This does the job. But if you notice, it breaks the swipe function for some reason. Try to swipe in my code and your code. My swipe is working well. But with yours, after swiping like two times if you try to swipe again it doesn't work. Or is it just me.

Comment: You're right.. I think it's because the slider should be able to animate only if not in animation.. try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbcgp